# How to use amazon LEX?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex, netflix, paytm

How can I develop a chatbot using Amazon Lex that not only comprehends user prompts but also learns and adjusts its responses over time, akin to the capabilities exhibited by ChatGPT?

I explored Amazon Lex to build a chatbot, expecting it to understand user prompts and adapt its responses based on interactions. However, I encountered challenges in understanding intent definition and integrating with other AWS services, hindering the chatbot's learning capabilities.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is too broad. AWS Lex is an entire platform, so we can't tell you every detail you need to implement a system using it. Try to build something and if you run into a *particular* problem, ask again.